# How to handle DATEFIRST when using DATEPART

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
-- SET DATEFIRST to U.S. English default value of 7.  
SET DATEFIRST 7;
SELECT
  @@DATEFIRST;
SELECT
  GETDATE()
, DATEPART(dw , GETDATE()) AS DayOfWeek;  
-- January 1, 1999 is a Friday. Because the U.S. English default   
-- specifies Sunday as the first day of the week, DATEPART of 1999-1-1  
-- (Friday) yields a value of 6, because Friday is the sixth day of the   
-- week when you start with Sunday as day 1.  

SET DATEFIRST 3;
SELECT
  @@DATEFIRST;
-- Because Wednesday is now considered the first day of the week,  
-- DATEPART now shows that 1999-1-1 (a Friday) is the third day of the   
-- week. The following DATEPART function should return a value of 3.  
SELECT
  GETDATE()
, DATEPART(dw , GETDATE()) AS DayOfWeek;
SET DATEFIRST 7;
```

How do we handle getting the DATEPART (1 = Sunday always) irregardless of DATEFIRST setting?

I really don't want to do a case and subtract...

Comment: you can have a table with name of the weekday and the `DayOfWeek` with the values you want, and use `DATENAME` instead of `DATEPART` (and then join it to your table). Kind of cumbersome, but it should work

Comment: The mod is where it is at.  I didn't want to do a `case @@datefirst when 1...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this always seems ridiculous to me, how about

```
select datediff(day,0, getdate()) % 7
```

where 6 represents Sunday

or you could do

```
select (datediff(day,0, '2016-07-31') - 5) % 7
```

to get Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue = 3  ... etc

or you could do this fiddle

```
select (datepart(weekday,get_date()) + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
```

seems to work for all datepart

```
    set datefirst  5

select (datepart(weekday,'2016-07-31') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-01') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-02') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-03') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-04') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-05') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-06') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
select (datepart(weekday,'2016-08-07') + @@datefirst - 1) % 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This code selects Monday as the first day of week whatever the setting in your engine:

```
((datepart(DW, @YourDateVariable) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7) + 1
```

by adding `@@DATEFIRST` value before the modulus operator it neglects the datefirst setting in your SQL engine.

The value 5 is to make Monday as the first day of the week
To make Sunday as the first day of the week add 6 
to make saturday as the first day of the week then add 0 
and so on the rest of the day weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but instead of doing the subtraction you can just set it to 7 and then back to what ever it was after your `DATEPART`

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
SELECT DATEPART(dw , GETDATE())             --6

SET DATEFIRST 3;

DECLARE @currentDatefirst int = @@DATEFIRST
SELECT @@DATEFIRST                          --3

SET DATEFIRST 7;
SELECT DATEPART(dw , GETDATE())             --6
SET DATEFIRST  @currentDatefirst
SELECT @@DATEFIRST                          --3
```

Comment: Nah, I don't want to change the server settings

Comment: presumably you can add/subtract @@DATEFIRST fromthe answer, do a % 7, then add 1 - in some way -

Comment: Using SET DATEFIRST does not change the setting on the server, only the current session.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't think so, @@ is global

Comment: I think@Sean Lange is right, it is only in the current session you are working in, but you'd be better trying out the 'rotation' using modular arithmetic I've attempted to work out - it's basically saying if it is 3 instead of 7, then it'll all rotate by 4, so put it back to where it would have been

Comment: @DanAndrews That's not true. If you go to [@@DATEFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx) it clearly says `Returns the current value, for a session, of SET DATEFIRST.`

Comment: I stand corrected.  However if that's the case, this is misleading: `SET DATEFIRST specifies the first day of the week. The U.S. English default is 7, Sunday.
This language setting affects the interpretation of character strings as they are converted to date values for storage in the database, and the display of date values that are stored in the database. This setting does not affect the storage format of date data. In the following example, the language is first set to Italian. `

Comment: @dan andrews - the whole @@datefirst setting seems to me to be 100 times more likely to cause an error, than ever prevent an error arising from  the obscure notion that SQL should tell someone what the day order is in any particular country.  A guess it's a design by committee aberration.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Yeah, unfortunately my code may be ran in other countries...  I think it's silly and arbitrary, why can't Sunday be 1 universally and code around it if you're in a different country?  /rhetorical